# MAUI Blazor - .mjs files in disclassified as "appliation/octet-stream"

Tags: blazor, maui, pdf.js, maui-blazor

I'm trying to include the [Prebuilt PDFjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/) files into our project.
I am including them via script tag as recommended by the library like so:

```
<script src="pdfjs/build/pdf.mjs" type="module"></script>
<script src="pdfjs/web/viewer.mjs" type="module"></script>
```

The problem is that they cannot be loaded:

```
pdf.mjs:1  Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Just using `pdfjs/build/pdf.mjs` and changing the file extension to `js` works to display a file.
Changing the extension on `pdfjs/web/viewer.mjs` for deeper functionality does not work anymore.

I would like to follow [this](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/components/simpleviewer.mjs) example, but I would need to enable `.mjs` files in MAUI Blazor.

Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

This error message says that your web-server isn't correctly configured, since it returns an incorrect MIME type for *.mjs files. You'll need to update the server configuration to return text/javascript for such files.

Here is the GitHub issue about [Getting 'MIME type' errors which prevent PDF display](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/17296), You can check the answers to solve the issue.

**Update**

I check the blazor document and finally found something useful. You can read this document about [Configure Request Filtering in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis) to set the configurations. Besides , I find the [Configuration Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap#configuration-sample).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I guess my question was "how do I configure that in MAUI Blazor?" as that technology is not using a web server

Comment: I check the blazor document and finally found something useful. You can read this document about [Configure Request Filtering in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis). Besides , I find the [Configuration Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap#configuration-sample).

Comment: Oh that looks really promising! Thank you!

Comment: I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Did this solve your issue?

Comment: Hi, I have actually not gotten to try this, yet, as other issues required my attention. I will make sure to comment if this worked. If you update your answer, I can also accept it then.